# PHP SOAP call empty response (Authorization header)

Tags: php, soap, sage

I want to call a soap API, to save data to Sage X3 version 12.
I'm using this code:

```
$options = array(
      'login' => $username,
      'password' => $password,
  );

  $api = parent::__construct($url, $options);
  $result = parent::__soapCall($function_name, $arguments, $options, $input_headers, $output_headers);
  return parent::__getLastResponse();
```

My PHP class extends `SoapClient`

I'm using basic auth with pre-emptive auth, but I get always an empty response.
Is there any problem in my code and why I get an empty response?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the arguments in an extra array like so

```
try {
    $result = parent::__soapCall($function_name, [$arguments], $options, $input_headers, $output_headers);
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```

If that does not work, check out for a SoapFault Exception and look into the error message.

You also should have a look at the [Client creation](https://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.construct). Here you can put in the credentials for the WSDL and control in the options *trace* and *exceptions*. If you have it disabled, then enable it. Usually, it is enabled by default.

Comment: I've already added a catch but there is no message

Comment: Because you posted a new question with asking on how to parse, did this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

The essence of the soap protocol is the http protocol. You can output the XML information you requested through a soap operation in PHP, then call this interface through postman, and put the xml content into postman to query the response results. Remember to set the raw option in postman. , the data format is xml. I have been troubleshooting this way before. I'm sorry that I didn't record how PHP outputs the XML requested by soap, but I am sure it can be exported.